# Godaddy linux hosting The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Tags: php, apache, godaddy, linux

I'm getting following error on GoDaddy economy linux hosting. How to fix that.

> The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is
>   not loaded

Error can be found at following url: http://lankaitpsl.com/

Comment: Remove any non-default _php.ini_ files in your root and `public_html` directories. If that doesn't help, then contact their support (it's 24/7 by phone and by chat).

Comment: ini file I tried. But it normally require restart. How to load the edited file on godaddy?

Comment: I would contact support and ask them to reset the account to its default, and be careful not to modify or override their default `php.ini` file. Alternatively, if you have an issue contacting support, you can reset the account by cancelling it under _Hosting_ in _My Account_, and then just use the credit that will show up there afterwards to start a fresh hosting account.